# Windows Server 2003 4GT Performance?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Does having 4 Gigabyte Tuning enabled cause a performance hit?

Comment: Do you mean does it decrease performance?

Comment: I am talking in the context of a server that hosts a bunch of web services.  So like an increase in response time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 32-bit apps that could use more than 2GB of virtual memory (4GT increases it to 3GB) then yes, you might benefit from enabling it. If your apps are network or IO heavy however, the memory available to those operation will be reduced and you may experience degraded performance. It really depends on the situation and the apps you're running. Experimenting may be the best way to find out.

[Microsoft's article on 3GT explains in more detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).